# Passing huge amount of small requests by using Javascript(Ajax) to PHP (logging into mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, request

would it be the right way to solve such problem?

**Problem:**

there will be amount of requests (200-400 per second) coming from users browsers through Javascript (Ajax) to my PHP node (single .php file), which will be logging some information to mysql database (e.g. user-agent, screen size, other user's public data). The amounts of single request sent information will be small (1-2kb).

What can you advice to prevent my server (or database) (1Core 2.5Ghz 1 GB RAM from dying from such amount of requests?

Or i should not worry about such amounts of requests at all?

Thanks

Comment: You should run a benchmark testing.

Comment: @TheAlpha simple timing checks? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use DVM's to see whats taking up the most worker time.  If you're on linux I'd also recommend watching \ checking your htop report to see how much strain is being put on your core in real time.  Here's a good DVM to use if to see what's taking up your worker time.  Unless you're doing something inefficient query wise you shouldn't have any issues though, but the only way to know for sure is benchmarking.

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
```